# Ionic 4 - ESRI JavaScript API 4.11 - How I can access the Map and MapView after created?

Tags: javascript

I'm programming a Ionic 4 App that shows a map with ArcGIS API for JavaScript.

I'm using esri-loader and I'm getting the map displayed, but I have a problem:

I'm trying to get the MapView in a variable for use in other function, but I get this error when I click the button "go location":

**ERROR TypeError: this.mapView.goTo is not a function**

tab2.page.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Map Tab 2
    </ion-title>
    <ion-button (click)="goLocation()">go location</ion-button>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <div id="map" #map ></div>
</ion-content>
```

tab2.page.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { loadModules } from 'esri-loader';

@component({
selector: 'app-tab2',
templateUrl: 'tab2.page.html',
styleUrls: ['tab2.page.scss']
})
export class Tab2Page implements OnInit {

@ViewChild('map') mapEl: ElementRef;
mapView: any;

constructor( public platform: Platform) {}

ngOnInit() {
this.mapView = this.getGeo();
}

async getGeo() {

  // Reference: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/platform/Platform/#ready
  await this.platform.ready();

  // Load the ArcGIS API for JavaScript modules
  const [Map, MapView]: any = await loadModules([
      'esri/Map',
      'esri/views/MapView'
  ])
      .catch(err => {
          console.error('ArcGIS: ', err);
      });

  console.log('Starting up ArcGIS map');

  const map = new Map({
      basemap: 'streets-navigation-vector'
  });

  // Inflate and display the map
  const mapView = new MapView({
      // create the map view at the DOM element in this component
      container: this.mapEl.nativeElement,
      // center: [-56.1665054, -34.9180854],
      zoom: 15,
      map: map
  });

  await mapView.when(function() {
    console.log('cargado mapa 1***', mapView);
    // mapView.goTo([-56.1665054, -34.9180854]);
    return mapView;
  }, function(error) {
    // Use the errback function to handle when the view doesn't load properly
    console.log('The view resources failed to load: ', error);
  });
}

goLocation() {
console.log('go location');
this.mapView.goTo([-56.1665054, -34.9180854]);
}
}
```

Questions:

1) esri-loader is the best option to access esri javascript API from Ionic now?

2) How I can access Map and MapView outside getGeo function?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your mapView is an element reference in your HTML. What you probably want to do is to have your ESRI map view be stored in a class variable.
I think below would work:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { loadModules } from 'esri-loader';

@component({
selector: 'app-tab2',
templateUrl: 'tab2.page.html',
styleUrls: ['tab2.page.scss']
})
export class Tab2Page implements OnInit {

@ViewChild('map') mapEl: ElementRef;
mapView: any;

esriMapView: any; 

constructor( public platform: Platform) {}

ngOnInit() {
this.mapView = this.getGeo();
}

async getGeo() {

  // Reference: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/platform/Platform/#ready
  await this.platform.ready();

  // Load the ArcGIS API for JavaScript modules
  const [Map, MapView]: any = await loadModules([
      'esri/Map',
      'esri/views/MapView'
  ])
      .catch(err => {
          console.error('ArcGIS: ', err);
      });

  console.log('Starting up ArcGIS map');

  const map = new Map({
      basemap: 'streets-navigation-vector'
  });

  // Inflate and display the map
  this.esriMapView = new MapView({
      // create the map view at the DOM element in this component
      container: this.mapEl.nativeElement,
      // center: [-56.1665054, -34.9180854],
      zoom: 15,
      map: map
  });

  await this.esriMapView.when(function() {
    console.log('cargado mapa 1***', mapView);
    // mapView.goTo([-56.1665054, -34.9180854]);
    return this.esriMapView;
  }, function(error) {
    // Use the errback function to handle when the view doesn't load properly
    console.log('The view resources failed to load: ', error);
  });
}

goLocation() {
console.log('go location');
this.esriMapView.goTo([-56.1665054, -34.9180854]);
}
}
```

I have an angular app that I use as starters for ESRI based apps here: https://github.com/Daimonos/jdhc-esri-starter/

I like to keep my map in a service so I can access it from other parts of the app via DI. I'm not sure how extensible it is to Ionic though

Comment: For your information, the author of this question hasn’t been back since a couple weeks after they asked the question — ten months ago — so don’t expect a lot of feedback.  It’s OK; we consider this site to be a knowledge base, and other people might benefit from this answer — but it might be another year before that happens.  Since you’re new here, you might want to focus on more current questions, where there’s a better chance that your contribution will get some attention.